# Как запустить vue.js приложение на express?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, vite

Вопрос такой, как сделать так чтобы после запуска сервера он сам запускал приложение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение находится в src/main.js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А при чем тут Vue вообще? Хотите просто запускать рядом vue, то выполняйте команду через `exec()` (подключив `child_process`)

Comment: Переформулирую, мне нужно запустить сервер, после этого чтобы сервер запустил приложение...

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь реализовать? SSR?